# What is the difference between 嘱咐 and 吩咐?

Tags: meaning, difference

Both of them seem to be able to be used to mean instruct. Am I right in saying that you can 嘱咐 and 吩咐 someone to study hard? If so, what is the difference in meaning between these two terms?

Comment: I wouldn't use either term to express "instructing" somebody to "study hard," as you put it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the most basic level they both mean "to tell", but they are not exactly the same - there is some nuanced differences.

- `吩咐` is closer to English **"to instruct"**. It is often used to describe a superior, or elder, telling their juniors to do something. Thus, it carries the connotation of a verbal command, almost ordering someone to do something. But it is less forceful outright than 命令, "to command".
- `嘱咐` in contrast is more even, and thus closer to English **"to ask"** or **"to urge"**. It is also used to convey concern, although it doesn't necessary carry any connotations of concern by itself.

Despite these nuances, for the most part the meanings are similar enough that they **can** be used interchangeably. That's why you'll also find them listed as synonyms.

Examples:

1. `他爸媽吩咐他要照顧好妹妹` : His parents ***told him*** to take good care of his sister. Alternatively: *"instructed him"*, or *"ordered him"*.
2. `他爸媽嘱咐他要照顧好妹妹` : His parents ***bade him*** take good care of his sister. Alternatively: *"asked him"*, or *"urged him"*.

Note that apart from the meaning of "to tell", 嘱咐 has a second meaning **"to entrust**", or **"to charge"**.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Semaphore,    `嘱咐`is more polite and more serious.
If he says,"Could you...", he is doing `嘱咐`.
If he says,"Do as I command!" he is doing `吩咐`.
Examples above are just make it more black and white.
By the way I'm chinese and my English grammar isn't very good.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

1. 吩咐 just like the command.
2. 嘱咐 just like the parents told something to son or ...  kindly

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: what did you mean ?

Comment: you might wanna check out http://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer "How do I write a good answer?"

Comment: thanks for your notice, i'll correct at next time. thank you so much again.

Comment: you can click 'edit' and add some more info - otherwise you might find your post deleted. just a heads up